# UIActivityIndicatorView added from StoryBoard not being displayed unless added programmatically as a sub view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uistoryboard

I added a UIActivityIndicatorView using StoryBoard and connecting an IBOutlet to my view controller:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

And on the interface builder it looks like this:

[image: IB]

Then I use use these two methods to start and stop the animation...

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

and

```
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

But my activity indicator is not being displayed unless I explicitly add it programmatically as a sub view:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [(UIWebView *)[self view] addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
    [(UIWebView *)[self view] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.webURL]];
}
```

Is this a expected behavior? Why do I need to add it programmatically as a sub view?

Answer (score 0):

You can put UIActivityIndicatorView on the UIView in storyboard. If you change base view from UIWebview to UIView, the problem solves.

```
UIView
|- UIWebview
|- UIActivityIndicatorView
```

Comment: Any particular reason why it just doesn't works when the hierarchy is as I tried first?